# Unable to round up the output values

Tags: matlab

I am getting output like this:

```
mhat =

  Columns 1 through 5

     0     0     1     1     1
```

When I write this output to file, using this code:

```
% write output to text file:
 fileID = fopen('myoutput.txt','w');
 fprintf(fileID,'%1f \n',mhat);
 fclose(fileID);
```

I am getting output with leading zeros like this

```
0.000000 
0.000000 
1.000000 
1.000000 
1.000000
```

But I am expecting output like this:

```
0 
0 
1 
1 
1
```

How do I get rid of the leading zeros? I have tried rounding but it is not happening. Help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are *trailing* 0's.  And rounding won't help; *numerically*, these are the values you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print integer, you should use

```
fprintf(fileID,'%d\n',mhat);
```

The '%1f' means print as a float with at least 1 character. Alternatively, you can use '%1.0f' to specify 0 decimal after the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a value w/o decimal places, you have to tell `fprintf` that; for example, you could use `%1.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

Use  ‘%g‘ to format your data in a condensed format:

```
fprintf('%g',1.00) % prints 1
fprintf('%g',1.01) % prints 1.01
```